# LaTeX3: implement a stack of integers

Tags: latex3, stack

I can see at least 3 different approaches to implement a stack of integers

1. with a sequence (seq)
2. with a comma separated list (clist)
3. with an array of integers (intarray)

Points 1 or 2 are very similar

Of course it depends on the usage, here are some facts for my own purpose:

- the maximum size of the stack is not known in advance but is around 10 to 20
- the stack operations are called as frequently as sectioning commands

How to make a decisions between these designs ?

Here is a POC using a clist:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\int_new:N \l_my_int
\clist_new:N \l_my_stack

\int_set:Nn \l_my_int { 421 }
\clist_push:Nx \l_my_stack { \int_use:N \l_my_int } % push 421
\clist_log:N \l_my_stack
\int_set:Nn \l_my_int { 123 }
\clist_push:Nx \l_my_stack { \int_use:N \l_my_int } % push 123
\clist_log:N \l_my_stack

\int_set:Nn \l_my_int { 0 } % reset

\clist_pop:NN \l_my_stack \l_tempa_tl
\int_set:Nn \l_my_int { \l_tempa_tl }
\int_log:N \l_my_int % retrieve 123

\clist_pop:NN \l_my_stack \l_tempa_tl
\int_set:Nn \l_my_int { \l_tempa_tl }
\int_log:N \l_my_int % retrieve 421

\end{document}
```

and the log file reads

```
The comma list \l_my_stack contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {421}.
The comma list \l_my_stack contains the items (without outer braces):
>  {123}
>  {421}.
> \l_my_int=123.
> \l_my_int=421.
```

One can replace `clist` by `seq` and have the same result.

Comment: Do you need to have linear access time? Or can we assume you'll only ever want to push/pop?

Comment: Only global push/pop operations.

Comment: Either `seq` or `clist` fits your requirement.